# Can I somehow ignore uncomitted transactions which are causing the database to go into recovery?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database which I have inherited which is just a collection of static data in seperate tables with no relations between tables. It is essentially just a number of tables which are the results of queries run against other databases. No-one else has access to the database. It turns out this hasn't been backed up.

A query was running over the weekend and something happened, perhaps a power cut. Now when I start SQL Server the database in question goes into recovery. Normally I would just leave this and let the recovery finish but in this case having left it a few hours I looked back and the estimated time to completion is 4.5 days!!!

Now, I'm not bothered about anything which happened as a result of the query which I ran over the weekend, I don't actually need the results of that anyhow now. All the query was doing was creating a new table, reading data from existing tables, no writing to existing tables. I can recreate almost everything in the database by running the original queries which will just take a few hours. My biggest problem is that I need access to the database, I can't wait 4.5 days!

Is there a way I can delete the transaction log, accepting that it won't recover whatever it was interruped over the weekend, so that SQL will stop trying to recover the database so I can carry on using the data within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't delete it, just in case you run into problems. If space isn't an issue create a copy of the original files with the instance offline, rename the original (so they aren't found on restart) then try:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase 
ON (FILENAME = [mdf path]) FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

Comment: Thanks that's really useful. One of my colleagues also mentioned another possible solution which is to set the database into EMERGENCY mode and use `DBCC CHECKDB (database_name, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)` which also seems to work and was quick

Comment: That works, however since you mentioned that you don't have a backup, this operation is on your original database. Mark's suggestion is saver in a sence that you are working on a copy.